# Clients want to use SSO with our Forge integration

Tags: autodesk-forge

We have clients asking to use SSO when logging in to BIM 360 through our app integration. Older posts indicate this isn't supported in Forge's OAuth. Is this supported yet?

Answer (score 0):

Autodesk SSO is supported on Forge, however BIM360/Forge do not yet support others SSO such as google, apple, etc... - There is multiple sample showing the 3legged OAuth workflow using the Autodesk SSO. [Here is one as an example.](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-bim360reports)

Now if you want to use SSO from other organisations, note that this will be supported in future, so you may re-ask the question in future.

You could also decide to use a workaround that we did demo in [this example](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/bim360appstore-data.management-nodejs-transfer.storage), the workaround consists in asking the user to login twice the first time he visits your application (once on Autodesk SSO, and a second time on the other SSO) and bind the two systems in your database. Since you can refresh the 3legged token with a 14days period, you can keep your application connected to Forge/BIM360 as long you want. Note this is only valid for Forge; you cannot use that technique to log on the BIM360 application interface, only using Forge to work with BIM360 data.

Answer (score 0):

Further Update(2023/10/26), Single Sign-On now is available with all Autodesk plans, check the announcement at
https://adsknews.autodesk.com/en/news/single-sign-on-now-available/

Customers can now help themselves to integrate their SSO workflow with Autodesk by following https://help.autodesk.com/view/SSOGUIDE/ENU/?guid=SSOGUIDE_Okta_Guide_About_Single_Sign_on_SSO_Before_you_begin_html .